# Icon in Navigation Drawer always square :-(

Tags: android, navigation

How to make icon in my Navigation Drawer rectangle like original size?

Comment: like original size means what? As per size of your image or Android Standard size of navigation icon?

Comment: you can check this link for more details https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs

Comment: my icon is rectangle but it always resize to square, like screenshot above @Abhishek

Comment: is navigation icon always square? @AmjadKhan

Comment: If you want to use it in rectangle size then it is not possible with Navigation View. Because navigation view icons are decided by "<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size">48dp</dimen>" this property. You can override it in your dimens but you cant change it to rectangle. You need to do some custom view.

Comment: if you need rectanlge icon you need to customize your icon or you need to use custom navigation

Comment: include tools:override="true" nad in dimens file <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>

Comment: Don't do those override system values, create custom `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to achieve for best practice

Comment: ok, it's easier if i change my image to square. and i can custom icon size with override it. if i have more time, may be i'll try use custom view thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default if you are using `menu` resource with items to populate Navigation drawer it will have equal `width` and `height`.

Alternatively, you can create your own `listview` with custom list_item for Navigation Drawer and use it to populate your own data with your Custom `UI`.

Please refer this link to do so : [Android Nav Drawer](https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)